# Join data between different indexes in elastic search where one field has a list of ids where each maps to an id in the other index

Tags: database, elasticsearch, join

I have 2 indexes. One contains some data about a Product. This index already exists and is being used in multiple places.
I want to create a new index about a users Wishlist which can contain multiple products. Every user can contain multiple wishlists.
**I want to fetch all products, given a users id and wishlist name.**.

- I AM allowed to structure the WISHLIST index in any way i wish, but no major change can occur in the Product index.
- It would also be great if the solution allows for pagination.

```
INDEX PRODUCT
[{
productid: 123,
name: abc,
available: true
},{
productid: 456,
name: abcder,
available: false
} ]

INDEX USER_WISHLIST
[{
userid: 1,
wishlist_name: xyz,
product_ids: [123, 456]
},
{userid: 2,
wishlist_name: pqr,
product_ids: [123]
},
{userid: 1,
wishlist_name: yyy,
product_ids: [456]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### Elasticsearch does not support traditional SQL-like joins between indices.

However, Elasticsearch provides an [enrich](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/enrich-setup.html) processor that can be used to add data from existing indices into a new index. This can be used as a workaround to achieve a similar result.

Here's an example for you:

1. First, create an enrich policy that defines which indices to enrich, the field to match on, and the fields to include in the enriched data:

```
PUT /_enrich/policy/product_policy
{
  "match": {
    "indices": "product",
    "match_field": "productid",
    "enrich_fields": ["name", "available"]
  }
}
```

2. Then, execute the policy:

```
POST /_enrich/policy/product_policy/_execute
```

3. Next, create a pipeline that uses the enrich processor to enrich documents as they are indexed into the USER_WISHLIST index:

```
PUT _ingest/pipeline/enrich_pipeline
{
  "processors": [
    {
      "enrich": {
        "policy_name": "product_policy",
        "field": "product_ids",
        "target_field": "product_details"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

4. Now, when you index documents into the USER_WISHLIST index, use the pipeline:

```
PUT /user_wishlist/_doc/1?pipeline=enrich_pipeline
{
  "userid": 1,
  "wishlist_name": "xyz",
  "product_ids": [123, 456]
}
```

The resulting document in the USER_WISHLIST index will have an additional field "product_details" that contains the product name and availability for each product id in the "product_ids" field.

Here is the official Elasticsearch enrichment example: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/match-enrich-policy-type.html